# Images In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a small application where there are multiple images displayed and when user clicks on any one of the images it gets bigger and replaces the image that is in middle.
But I am not getting the clicked image.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="text/javascript">

function swapImage(this.id) {
document.write("In SwapImage");
switch (this.id) {
 case img2:
   IMG1.src = "component1/images/image1.jpg"
   intImage = 2
   return(false);
 case img3:
   IMG1.src = "component1/images/image1.jpg"
   intImage = 2
   return(false);
 case img4:
   IMG1.src = "component1/images/image1.jpg"
   intImage = 2
   return(false);
 }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
 <IMG id="IMG1" name="IMG1" src="image1.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
 <IMG id="IMG2" name="IMG2" height="40px" width="40px" src="image1.jpg" onclick="swapImage(this.id);"> 
 <IMG id="IMG3" name="IMG3" height="40px" width="40px" src="image2.jpg" onclick="swapImage();">
 <a href="#">
   <IMG id="IMG4" name="IMG4" height="40px" width="40px" src="image1.jpg" onclick="swapImage();">
 </a>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: doesn't javascript need semicolon line terminators in blocks of more than one line?  If so, I'd expect the missing semicolons to cause the interpreter to fail to interpret the function, and error out or ignore it.  Are you testing in IE or Fx?  Have you looked at the error console (in IE double click the little yellow triangle at the bottom left corner of the page, in FX, go to Tools - Error Console)?

Comment: @atk JavaScript tries to automatically insert missing semicolons. It shouldn't be relied upon though.

Comment: `function swapImage(this.id)`? Seriously?

Comment: +1 Upvoted the question as there is no reason to downvote. User is obviously new to scripting and should be helped, not penalized by "elitist" coders.

Comment: @KevinP You are right...why penalize newbies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
function swapImage(src) {
  document.getElementById("IMG1").src = src;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
 <IMG id="IMG1" src="image1.jpg" height="100px" width="100px">
 <IMG id="IMG2" height="40px" width="40px" src="image1.jpg" onclick="swapImage(this.src);"> 
 <IMG id="IMG3" height="40px" width="40px" src="image2.jpg" onclick="swapImage(this.src);">
 <IMG id="IMG4" height="40px" width="40px" src="image1.jpg" onclick="swapImage(this.src);">
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

There are some errors in your code, for example:

- The document.write should not be used like this
- You are doing switch/case on non existing variables (img2, img3, img4)
- JavaScript is case sensitive. IMG4 does not equal img4
- return is a statement. If you want to return false, you write `return false;`
- Each statement should end with a semicolon.
- HTML tag names should be written in lowercase
- this.id is used incorrectly in the swapImage function (shouldn't be there at all)..
- ..but it is correct when used in `IMG2`..
- ..but is incorrect in `IMG3` and `IMG4`
- The img tag should not have a "name" attribute

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Helgi,
but the image is not changing.

Comment: Could be a casing issue? The image tag has id: IMG1, the javascript looks for img1? Just a thought.

Comment: @KevinP Yes, there was a casing issue. Also, the language attribute contained "text/javascript" instead of just "javascript".

Answer (score 1):

img3 and img4 are missing the this.id reference, so the method doesn't know about the image being clicked...  is that what you were asking about?

Comment: Hey, also the method should take the ID, and you should change the document.getElementById() to take this new param, so it should be: swapImage(id) { .. }, and getElementById should use this new id variable...

Answer (score 1):

To add to Fabian's answer, in your function your parameter should be `id`, not `this.id`, and your switch statement should do the same, like so:

```
function swapImage(id) {
  switch (id) {
    // case statements
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the question is: "Why does this script fail?".

There are several issues with your script:

1. `document.write()` is not supposed to be used for logging. It can easily corrupt your page.
2. You don't set the `IMG1` variable. You probably wont something like `var IMG1 = document.getElementById("IMG1");` at the start of your script.
3. The cases in the switch statement have to be string literals. Instead of `case img3:` you have to write `case "img3":`

Comment: ...not to forget, that `function swapImage(this.id) {` is a syntax error (you can't set `this.id` as variable declaration of a function).

Comment: Thanks guys. but I feel the function swapimage isnt getting executed. as the document.write() statement isnt executed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were trying to do (untested)?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var swapImage = function() {
            var IMG1=document.getElementById("img1");
            return function(){
                switch (this.id) {
                    case "img2":
                        IMG1.src = "component1/images/image2.jpg";
                        intImage = 2;
                    break;
                    case "img3":
                        IMG1.src = "component1/images/image3.jpg";
                        intImage = 2;
                    break;
                    case "img4":
                        IMG1.src = "component1/images/image4.jpg";
                        intImage = 2;
                    break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <IMG id="img1" height="100px" width="100px" src="image1.jpg">
        <IMG id="img2" height="40px" width="40px" src="image2.jpg" onclick="swapImage();"> 
        <IMG id="img3" height="40px" width="40px" src="image3.jpg" onclick="swapImage();">
        <IMG id="img4" height="40px" width="40px" src="image4.jpg" onclick="swapImage();">

    </body>
</html>
```

Please note that is not a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

what about this.

```
<style>
    ul li{
        float: left;
        margin:10px;
        list-style: none;
    }
</style>

  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="" id="zoomImg" height="200" width="300" /></div>
  <ul>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&amp;text=First" alt="img1" onclick="swapImage(this.src)"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&amp;text=Second" alt="img2" onclick="swapImage(this.src)"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&amp;text=Third" alt="img3" onclick="swapImage(this.src)"></li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function swapImage(src){
         var zoomImg = document.getElementById('zoomImg');
          zoomImg.src = src;
      }
  </script>
```